# Yesod Form syntax

Tags: forms, haskell, yesod

I have been working my way through this tutorial:

http://pbrisbin.com/posts/developing_web_applications_with_yesod/

```
 lemonadeForm :: Form Lemonade
 lemonadeForm = renderTable $ Lemonade
     <$> pure Nothing
     <*> areq (selectField optionsEnum) "Size" Nothing
     <*> pure 0.0
     <*> areq intField "Quantity" Nothing
```

I have several questions about this syntax.

1) It says a few lines later in the tutorial that "The lines that use pure provide values when processed, but don't actually show any fields." Does this mean that otherwise the form would not know the meaning of `Nothing` and `0.0`?

2) What does the syntax `<$>` and `<*>` mean respectively?

Comment: The following interpretation helped me: <$> is functors what $ is for functions: left of <$> is read last. At least this helped me understand what was going on. For <*> unfortunately, I could not come up with a useful analogy: follow the types as @sibi suggested.

Comment: The easiest way for me to read `<$>` and `<*>` is as normal function application. When you have an expression like `f <$> a <*> b <*> c`, you have to realize that what the author "wanted" to write was `f a b c`, but couldn't because all of `f`, `a`, `b`, `c` are wrapped in some kind of effect. `f <$> a <*> b <*> c` is then function application within this effectful context. Do read LYAH for a better intuition on Functors and Applicative Functors, they're important organizational and design tools in Haskell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does the syntax `<$>` and `<*>` mean respectively?

`pure` and `<*>` are two class methods of type class [`Applicative`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6-latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Control-Applicative.html), `<$>` is an infix synonym for `fmap`, which is one of the class methods of [`Functor`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6-latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Data-Functor.html).

[Chatper 11 Functors, Applicative Functors and Monoids](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) of [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) has a quite good introduction to `Functor` and `Applicative`, you may want to take a look.

Answer (score 3):

The datatype of `Lemonade` is as follows:

```
data Lemonade = Lemonade
    { lemonadeOrder :: Maybe OrderId
    , lemonadeSize  :: Size
    , lemonadePrice :: Price
    , lemonadeQty   :: Qty
    }
```

> The lines that use pure provide values when processed, but don't
>   actually show any fields.

What this means is that when the form is displayed as HTML in the browser, the fields for which `pure` has been used will not be shown. Although the value will be used internally, it won't be shown to the user. In your example, the fields for `lemonadeOrder` and `lemonadePrice` will not be shown up in the form.

> What does the syntax `<$>` and `<*>` mean respectively?

`<$>` is an alias for `fmap`.
`<*>` is used for Applicative style programming. You can get to know more about them by inspecting it's type and by reading [Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia) or other relevant materials.